# spark-shell in windows 7 is throwing \spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\..' was unexpected at this time

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop

I had downloaded spark 2.4.2 distribution and placed it under C:\Program Files (x86). I had also set SPARK_HOME and added SPARK_HOME to path. Now when I trying to open spark-shell using command prompt it is throwing following error:
C:\Users\Admin>spark-shell
\spark-2.4.2-bin-hadoop2.7\bin..' was unexpected at this time.

I am expecting it to launch spark shell

Comment: Your Java, and Spark home variable cannot contain spaces

Comment: Thanks it worked. I moved spark distribution to some other directory not having spaces. Set SPARK_HOME to new directory and it worked.